# Ascending sort between numbers in array

Tags: c, arrays, sorting, hex, insertion-sort

I need to sort between numbers in array.

input.txt:
0005
0006
FFFF
0007
0003
FFFF
0004
0002
0001
FFFF
0000

and output should be:
000     0005        0006        0000    0003        0005        0006        0007    0000        0001        0002        0003        0004        0005        0006        0007

FFFF in output as 0000, and sort them in between, but to use the numbers for whole array.
My code sorts them in ascending way, which is not corret output.
0001 0002 0003 0004 0005 0006 0007 FFFF FFFF FFFF

```
 // sort the integers
for(i = 1; i < count; i++)
{
    temp = array[i];
    j = i - 1;

    while( (temp < array[j])&&(j >= 0))
    {
        array[j + 1] = array[j];
        j = j - 1;
    }
array[j + 1] = temp;
}

for (i=0; i<count; i++)
{
    printf("%04X ", array[i]);
}
```

Comment: I don't understand what you are asking. Your required output does not match the input you gave.

Comment: @WeatherVane output should look like that. Currently I receive: 0000 0001 0002 0003 0004 0005 0006 0007 FFFF FFFF FFF. I am thinking to put "if statements" in "for loop" or inside "while". Have to try both.

Comment: `0xFFFF` is not necessarily `-1`. If you want `-1`, use `-1` and dont rely on implementation details unnecessarily.

Comment: @Olaf its done in hex format. -1 or any other FFFF, does not matter

Comment: @RyadKovach well please edit the question, so  there is a consistent problem statement and required answer. All I can see if numbers sprinkled everywhere.

Comment: @RyadKovach: Then you must not make the assumition `0xFFFF == -1`!

Comment: @WeatherVane Better ?

Comment: @Olaf My bad. But as input mainly will  FFFF be used, besides other hex. Thanks

Comment: Get the concepts right! `-1` is not a hex value. You confuse signed and unsigned values.

Comment: @Olaf Its not. Thats way should be to 0000 converted.

Comment: Write a function to do the sort. Give it the array start index as one of the parameters and let it work out the end index when it sees `FFFF`. Have the function sort and return the index of `FFFF`. Call the function in a loop with start index set to return value of previous loop invocation.

Comment: Parse the array until you find `FFFF`, replace it with `0000`. Sort the array up to this index, and print from `array[0]`. Repeat this process, printing from `array[1]`, and so on until the end of array. But I am still mystified by the last `0000` of the input, which seems to have vanished.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdint.h>
#include <inttypes.h>

#define MAX_DATA_SIZE 100

int main(void){
    const uint16_t block_end = 0xFFFF, input_end = 0x0000;
    uint16_t array[MAX_DATA_SIZE] = {0}, input_value;
    int count = 1;//array[0] = 0x0000

    FILE *fp = fopen("input.txt", "r");

    while(fscanf(fp, "%" SCNx16, &input_value)==1){
        if(input_value == block_end){
            for(int i = 0; i < count; ++i){
                printf("%04" PRIx16 "\n", array[i]);
            }
        } else if(input_value == input_end){
            break;
        } else {
            array[count++] = input_value;
            for(int i = count-1; i > 0 && array[i-1] > array[i]; --i){
                uint16_t temp = array[i];
                array[i] = array[i-1];
                array[i-1] = temp;
            }
            if(count == MAX_DATA_SIZE){
                fprintf(stderr, "There is a need to increase the size of the array.\n");
                exit(1);
            }
        }
    }

    fclose(fp);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: [DEMO](http://ideone.com/DBc14U)